# Using a class in a static arrayed list C#

Tags: list, class, generics, static

Here is what i would want to accomplish - i want this class globally accessible, and i need 6 instances of it. So basically it should be something like List[6] which would be initalized in a public static class...

```
class HH
{
    public string hand { get; set; }
    public string user { get; set; }
    public int z { get; set; }
    public int bb { get; set; }
    public int eff { get; set; }
    public int pos { get; set; }
    public string pre { get; set; }
    public string f { get; set; }
    public string t { get; set; }
    public string r { get; set; }

}


public static class tx
{
public static List<HH>[] HH = new List<HH>[6];
}
```

Now obv. this is wrong - but maybe you get the idea what i try to accomplish. Could someone give me an idea how i can accomplish that so that in my code i can access the elements of the class and read and write from and to it?

Comment: can you write more about your situation? (What you want to use it for and why), this still seems too little info (at least for me).

Comment: Yeah why do you need to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

"public static List[] HH = new List[6];"
I think this is not enough. You only initialized the array, but HH objects left. After that code, you may write a loop to instantiate every HH object.
I hope that would be helpful. But if not, it may be great if you can provide more detail.
:)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
public static class TX
{    
   public static List<HH> _HH { get; private set; } 

   static TX()
   {
       _HH = new List<HH>()
       {
          new HH(), new HH(), new HH(),
          new HH(), new HH(), new HH()
       };
   }

    internal class HH
    {
        public string hand { get; set; }
        public string user { get; set; }
        public int z { get; set; }
        public int bb { get; set; }
        public int eff { get; set; }
        public int pos { get; set; }
        public string pre { get; set; }
        public string f { get; set; }
        public string t { get; set; }
        public string r { get; set; }    
    }    
}
```

And use it like :

```
var hand = TX._HH[0].hand;
```

Comment: Thanks so much, thats what i was looking for. I had to change public static class to just class, otherwise there was a access incompatability and now if i would to set it e.g. i just do TX._HH[0].user = "xxx". Cheers